# Passing parameters to another class

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters, bundle

I have two classes one of them that I pass to sends two parameters which are 
1- file URL
2- file name
 because I dont want to create this class for every file I have

**first class passes the parameters from OnItemClickListener**

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    // pass parameters file name & file url

                  }
```

**the second class**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
OutputStream output=new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, filename));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following code :

**first class passes the parameters from OnItemClickListener**

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    // pass parameters file name & file url
                    Intent i = new Intent(FirstClass.this,SecondClass.this);
                    i.putExtra("FileName",fileName);
                    i.putExtra("FileURL",fileURL);
                    startActivity(i);

                  }
```

**the second class**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileName"); 
                    file_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileURL");
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
OutputStream output=new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, filename));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a [Bundle](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/17/android---passing-data-between-activities.aspx) and store the URL and file name in it. And then you can pass this bundle in the intent that calls the new activity. In the new class, you extract the information from the bundle using `getIntent().getExtras()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass fileName and fileURL from first class like following,

```
// pass parameters file name & file url
Intent i = new Intent(FirstClass.this,SecondClass.this);
i.putExtra("FileName",fileName);
i.putExtra("FileURL",fileURL);
startActivity(i);
```

and get from second activity as following,

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
filename = b.getString("fileName"); 
file_url = b.getString("fileURL");
```